# Virtualization not available. Flag `vmx` not shown while VT-d active in Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL in Win10. Instead, shows on Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL2 in Win11

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kvm-virtualization

I have 2 hardware-clone PCs. Both are a MSI GL75 9SEK, bought the very same day and identical hardware characteristics. Name them PC-A and PC-B.

CPU is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz` in both cases as per `lscpu`.

## OS installation history

Both had Windows 10.

- PC-A has not updated to Win11 and still runs Win10 with an Ubuntu 20.04 inside the WSL2.
- PC-B was updated to Win11 and then WSL2 was installed. It runs an Ubuntu 22.04 inside the WSL2.

## BIOS settings

Both PCs have the virtualization enabled in the BIOS:

[image: BIOS showing VT-d]

Both PCs have VT-d enabled.

## Ubuntu 20.04 shows no `vmx`

Then inside PC-A I search for the `vmx` in `/proc/cpuinfo` and there's no result:

[image: No vmx in PC-A]

Therefore I cannot use KVM for virtualization:

[image: No KVM possibilities]

## Ubuntu 22.04 shows `vmx`

Instead, doing the same command in PC-B `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i vmx` does show the results:

[image: vmx enabled in PC-B]

Therefore, I supposedly may use the KVM virtualization in it:

[image: KVM potentially available]

## Questions

- What/where should I look at to track down where `vmx` is being lost?
- How can I enable the `vmx` flag if it's not in the BIOS?

Comment: VMX is *only* visible from the BiOS and only settable there.  However, keep in mind that it partly depends on the WSL environment.  Not every WSL is WSL2 format, which is the format that supports virtualization.  Make sure your WSL on the computer not showing virtualization is in fact using WSL2 and your WSL is converted to WSL2 (which uses Hyper-V and virtualization which enables virtualization)